# Function vs Partial Function

Tags: functions, partial-functions

Generally speaking, can we say that "any function is a partial function"? I know what is exactly a partial function, but is it correct to imply that arbitrary function can be seen as a partial function?

Comment: If you have the definition of a partial function, does an ordinary function meet it?

Comment: Partial function is defined such as you have some domain, and partial function takes some subset of it, and maps every element of that subset into some image. But I do not see how any function can satisfy that?

Comment: If your function is $f: X \to Y$ it is a partial function with $X=X$.

Comment: Oh yeah, it seems statement is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A partial function $f: Z \to Y$ is usually defined to be an ordinary function $f: X \to Y$ where $X \subseteq Z$.  In your case, $Z=X$, so yes.

This would only go wrong if you defined a partial function $f: Z \to Y$ as an ordinary function $f: X \to Y$ for some subset $X \subset Z$, for then taking $X=Z$ would be prohibited.  However, I have never seen that in the literature.